# Trouble going from one form to another using buttons

Tags: c#, forms, button, navigation

[this is my frmMain image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EouwM.png)
I have been struggling with this all day. I have 7 buttons in my nav menu. I have my main form which all those buttons are placed  and 7 forms that I will connect to my 7 buttons. 1 form for each button. When I go to another form the previous form I opened is still there. I tried  using hide and close to exit the other forms but it was not working for me. I'm also using none border form

btnItems to frmItems
btnUsers to frmUsers
btnSuppliers to frmSuppliers
btnStocks to frmStocks (and so on with the 3 more buttons connected to different forms)

This is the code.

```
private void btnItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {frmItems op = new frmItems();
        op.Show();
      }

    private void btnSuppliers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        frmSuppliers op = new frmSuppliers();
        op.Show();


    }
```

Comment: Is this Windows Forms or WPF?

Comment: Windows form application.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't understand EXACTLY what you are trying to accomplish, is showing the forms as a modal dialog an option? This would ensure that a window must be closed before allowing control to go back to the main form and allow another window to be opened.

```
private void btnSuppliers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var op = new frmSuppliers())
        op.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

Comment: sorry for this I'm just a newbie in programming but i just added the photo of my frmMain so you can understand what I was trying to say.

Comment: We all begin somewhere. Did you try the snippet above? Is that more the type of behavior you were trying to achieve?

Comment: This is the main form i made. My problem is i cant connect this to my forms without making new ones if i click the button again it will make 2 frmItems and what my objective is when i click another button from the nav another form will open but the previous form that i opened would close.